# SQL: How can I order by a specific range of ID numbers, then time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, union

This code is very likely poorly written. It's my first foray into SQL - I'm taking on a project that isn't exactly my job so I'm trying to learn it as I go.

My two big problems right now:

1. **I need to separate ID numbers over a certain number. For our instances lets just say 1000. So any IDs Under 1000 displayed first, with their respective appointment times.**
2. **I run into an error while using ORDER BY because of a UNION I'm using in my code. It is:**

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

The error points to the line with END ASC. I've read online about including the whole thing as it's own SELECT statement and using that to reference in the ORDER BY code, but haven't had any luck.

The relevant code is below:

```
select substring(convert(nvarchar, a.time, 8), 1,5) Time
 , PersonID AS ID
 [BLAH BLAH BLAH]
from [BLAH BLAH BLAH]
where [BLAH BLAH BLAH]

union

select 'Alts'
 , PersonID
 [BLAH BLAH BLAH]
from [BLAH BLAH BLAH]
where [BLAH BLAH BLAH]

ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN PersonID <= 1000 THEN PersonID
            ELSE 1001
          END ASC,
          a.time
```

This ORDER BY at the bottom is what I'm trying to set up. The rest of the code seems to execute fine. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is "a.time" in the order by, you should refer it as "Time" since that's the alias for the column in the select.

Comment: Wow. Yep this was it. It returned the error "ambiguous column name" but I just changed it to something more specific and that fixed it. However, I'm still getting errors from the "order by case" for person ID

Comment: Oh, you might need to add then the case statement into the both select statements + give it an alias, and then sort by it or use the union as a derived query and do the sorting outside it.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a try. 

Also, is there a way to sort time so it counts 9:00, 10:00, 11:00, 12:00, 1:00, 2:00? Rather than 1:00, 2:00, 9:00, 10:00, etc?

Comment: You need to use time -data type instead of varchar

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about using the union as a derived query and sort outside it?